# Need Help Catching An ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException On A For Each Loop (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, foreach, catch-exception

## **HW3.java**

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW3 {

```
//Method Establishes Scanner For Inputing Hour
public static int Scanner() {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pay = x.nextInt();
    return pay;
}
        
public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Asks For Hour Input, Input Hours Into Variable
    System.out.println("Input Hours");
    int hour = Scanner();

    //Establish Array Of Employees With Name And Wage Categories
    Employee [] employee = new Employee[4];
    employee [0] = new Employee("Shinji Ikari", 15.50);     
    employee [1] = new Employee("Rei Ayanami", 21.35);  
    employee [2] = new Employee("Asuka Langley Soryu", 2.12);
    employee [3] = new Employee("Kaworu Nagisa", 20.01);
    
    //For Loop Running The showText Method From Employee.java For Each Employee In Array 
    try {
        for (Employee e : employee)     
            e.showText(hour);       
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException oob) {
        System.out.println("NO");
    }   
}
```

}

## **Employee.java**

public class Employee {

```
//Sets Private Variables That Defines "Employee"
private String name;
private double wage;
private double totalpay;

    //Employee Constructors For Name And Wage
    public Employee(String employeename, double hourlypay) {
        name = employeename;
        wage = hourlypay;
    }   
    
    //Returns The Name Value        
    public String getName() {           
        return name;        
    }
    
    //Sets ASnd Updates Name
    public void setName(String ename) {         
        name = ename;   
    }       
    
    //Returns The Wage Value
    public double getWage() {
        return wage;
    }
    
    //Sets And Updates Wage
    public void setWage(double hourlypay) {
        wage = hourlypay;
    }
    
    //Method That Subtracts A 30% Tax From Base Hourly Pay  
    public double getTotalPay() {       
        totalpay = wage - (wage*0.3);
        return totalpay;
            }

    //Method Takes Name, Wage, and Totalpay From Employee.java Alongside Hour From HW3.java To Place Them In The Printed Statement
    public void showText(int hoursworked) {
        try {System.out.printf("The employee " +name+ ", who earns $%.2f per hour, worked for " +hoursworked+ " hours last week and took home $%.2f after taxes.\n", wage, getTotalPay()*hoursworked);
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException oob) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
```

}

In this weekly paycheck estimator program I need to catch a possible ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when extracting an employee from my employee array. I have no idea how to test if my current placement of the exception program is correct because I don't know how to format an each loop to attempt to loop beyond the four employees I currently have in my main method. Is my current exception program placed correctly in the loop or do I need to place it somewhere else?

Comment: There is never a reason to catch an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You can test the array index beforehand, and your enhanced for loop will never go out of bounds. Don't use exceptions to control your program's flow.

Comment: Another problem: Why would you catch an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the showText method? This method doesn't perform any array operations.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch an exception if it isn't thrown. The try / catch statements *would* catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if it was thrown ... but it isn't thrown.

```
try {
    System.out.printf("The employee " + name + 
         ", who earns $%.2f per hour, worked for " +
         hoursworked + 
         " hours last week and took home $%.2f after taxes.\n", 
         wage, getTotalPay() * hoursworked);
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException oob) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

The code inside the code block is not operating on an array at all, so the exception cannot be thrown.

<sup>(Aside: the `printf` is misguided too.  You are using *both* string concatenation *and* formatting.  You can do it all with just formatting, and the code will be a lot more readable.)</sup>

```
try {
    for (Employee e : employee)     
        e.showText(hour);       
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException oob) {
    System.out.println("NO");
}
```

This is operating on the array, but it is doing it in a way that is guaranteed to not go beyond the bounds of the array.

If you wanted the above *cause* that exception (so that you can catch it) you could rewrite the loop like this:

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) // this loop is deliberately wrong    
        employee[i].showText(hour);       
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException oob) {
    System.out.println("NO");
}
```

Now you will get an exception when `i` is `4`.  But you wouldn't / shouldn't do that in a real program.  You should avoid using exception handling to implement "normal" control flow.  (Though what "normal" control flow means is open to interpretation!)

---

> Is the code correct?

Yes and no; see above.

- Yes because you *would* catch the exception if it was thrown.  And this code *does* compile.
- No because the exception *won't* be thrown.  Guaranteed.  Code that tries to catch an (unchecked) exception that cannot be thrown is redundant and misleading ... and therefore wrong.